# Plot superscripts in ggplot without losing leading zeroes

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Q:** *how do I plot superscripted text in `ggplot` but not lose leading zeroes?*

#### Problem

**Goal.** I am trying to plot text labels with superscripted information.
The superscript is the last two digits of the year of an
observation (e.g., 2018 is "18", 2005 is "05").

**Problem.** I can almost get this plot working correctly, but `ggplot`
swallows the leading zeroes.  For example: the superscript "18"
plots correctly as "18," but the superscript "05" plots
incorrectly as "5".

#### Example

Here's a toy example:

```
## libraries
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## example data
Dat <-
    tribble(~ state, ~ year, ~ x, ~ y,
            "MI",    2010,   1,   1,
            "CA",    2005,   2,   2,
            "NY",    2011,   3,   3,
            "AK",    2003,   4,   4,
            "IL",    2012,   5,   5)

## create the label: state with a superscripted year (e.g., MI^10, AK^03)
Dat$lab <-
    with(Dat,
         paste(state,
               "^{",
               substr(as.character(year), 3, 4),
               "}",
               sep = ""))

## plot the labels: note that the 0s in the superscripts disappear
ggplot(Dat,
       aes(x     = x,
           y     = y,
           label = lab)) +
    geom_text(parse = TRUE) +
    theme_bw()
```

It produces the following plot:

[image: example plot showing the problematic superscripts]

Note that `MI`, `NY`, and `IL` are plotted correctly with
two-digit superscripts, but `CA` and `AK` incorrectly have
single-digit superscripts.  **How do I keep the leading zeroes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add quotes around the number to be superscripted when you are pasting the expression together. This will format the number as a string inside the expression so that the leading zeroes will be retained. You can use the escape character `\` to add double quotes to the already double quoted string. Edit the "create the label" portion of your code as follows:

```
Dat$lab <-
  with(Dat,
       paste(state,
             "^{\"",
             substr(as.character(year), 3, 4),
             "\"}",
             sep = ""))
```

I tested this with ggplot2 2.2.1 just now and it works.